# How to export specific request to file using postman?

Tags: rest, postman, webapi

I want to export one specific request from a Postman extension (Chromium) and send it to another developer so that they can import it. How I can do this?

Comment: Here is how I write a response to a file and to console: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52959100/how-to-log-api-responses-to-console-and-save-to-a-data-file-using-pm-sendrequest The request shows in console. Hope this helps.

Comment: Apparently, you cannot. Add it to a new collection using "Save As" button. Open the request and expand "Save" button to see "Save As" button.

Comment: You can share your collection or request directly to a team workspace and collaborate on it with the other developer without having to go through import/export. More info here: https://learning.postman.com/docs/collaborating-in-postman/collaboration-intro/

Answer (score 225, accepted):

To do that you need to leverage the "Collections" feature of Postman. This link could help you: https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collections/creating_collections/

Here is the way to do it:

- Create a collection (within tab "Collections")
- Execute your request
- Add the request to a collection
- Share your collection as a file

Comment: is there is a way to export the response with it?

Comment: There is an 'export' option on collection for download and be able to import

Comment: is there any way that I can export a single request (not a collection) as a json

Comment: "export" is better than "share" as it works without sending your data to the Postman Server.

Comment: What a smart thought!

Comment: You're missing critical instructions.  You have to click ... Export Collection on the collection section to actually save to file.

Comment: @alaasdk yes, you can. Just create an example (top right).

Comment: Ahem. _specific_ request, not collection

Answer (score 120):

1. Click on the "Code" button upright of the request page.
2. From the opened window select cURL.
3. Copy and share the generated code.

[image]

You can use this curl request to import it into Postman.

> This discards variables, pre-request scripts, tests... or anything
> Postman-specific the request has.

Comment: Needless to say, this discards variables, pre-request scripts, tests... or anything Postman-specific the request has. But it's the only only way to export an individual request.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thanks for your comment, I quote your comment in my answer with your permission.

Comment: I don't see this option on Mac as of 2023. Yoel's answer worked for me though.

Answer (score 40):

If you want to export it as a file just do Any Collection (...) -> Export. There you should be able to choose collection version format and it will be exported in JSN file.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. "Export" ist the answer - not "share". For sharing you need a Postman account - and your collections are sent to Postman server, which is a big security issue in my opinion - most people have passwords in their collections.

Comment: There are other correct answers but this is my favorite because it is more concise in addressing the point that 'you can only export collections, not individual requests'

Answer (score 15):

In the **new version** of Postman, click on Code at the right of the screen, then select from the Code snippet dropdown.

[image]

Then you can choose which language format you are interested in.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

There is no direct option to export a single request from Postman.

You can create and export collections. [Here](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/importing-and-exporting-data/#exporting-collections) is a link to help with that.

Regarding the single request thing, you can try a workaround. I tried with the RAW body parameters and it worked.

What you can do is,

1. In your request tab, click on the 3 dots in the top right corner of your request panel/box.
   [image]
2. Select Code. This will open Generate Code Snippents window.
   [image]
3. Copy the cURL code and save it in a text file. Share this with who you want to.
   [image]
4. They can then import the request from the text file.
   [image]

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to the previous answers you knew how to save/download a request.

For people who are asking for a way to save/export the **response** you can use the arrow beside the "Send" button, click "Send and Download" to get the response in .json

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can export collection by clicking on arrow button

[image]

and then click on download collection button

Answer (score 3):

The workaround is to export the collection as explained in other answers or references. This will export all requests in that collection to JSON file.

Then edit the JSON file to remove the requests you do not want using any editor; this is very simple.

Look for `"item"` collection in file. This contains all your requests; one in each item. Remove the items you do not want to keep.

If you import this edited file in Postman where original collection already exists, Postman will ask you if you want to replace it or create a copy. If you want to avoid this, you may consider changing `"_postman_id"` and `"name"` under `"info"`. If original collection will not exist while importing edited collection, then this change is not needed.

[image: Screenshot]