# How to create JSON file from postman collection(s)

Tags: jmeter, postman, postman-collection, loadium

I want to convert my current Postman collection(s) to JMeter jmx files

I should be able to [convert in loadium](https://loadium.com/postman-to-jmeter-converter/#) by adding collection JSON file, But I don't find Export option anymore (even I'm sign in to postman), was it removed ?

How/where collection JSON are saved?

I didn't find a valid answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28965847/how-to-export-specific-request-to-file-using-postman) (sharing) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47399809/where-are-postman-collections-saved) (Postman uses LevelDB)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need to export your collection, this might help.

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/collections/data_formats

Or

https://youtu.be/bF8q8wvLs8A

Right click collection and choose Export: 
[image]

Comment: @user7294900 The export button is available in multiple places in the app. Not only in the context menu. It's there in case you're browsing the collection by clicking the '>' arrow over each collection. It's there inside the '...' over each collection.